# Loading multiple controllers in seperate files asynchronously with angular-loader and scriptjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-seed

I started an angular project using [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed), and with index-async.html it uses angular-loader and [script.js](https://github.com/ded/script.js) by default. I added two controllers to this project, each in two separate files.
The file for the first controller starts like this:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers').controller('FirstCtrl', ...
```

The file for the second controller starts like this:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers').controller('SecondCtrl', ...
```

And then in the main app.js file:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);
angular.module('myApp', [
  'myApp.controllers'
])
```

All three files were added to script.js:

```
$script([
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',

      'js/app.js',

      'js/controllers/first-ctrl.js',
      'js/controllers/second-ctrl.js',
    ], function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    });
```

When I run the app, sometimes it works, and sometimes I get the errors:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.20/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp.controllers
>
> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'FirstCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Note. I've left out routeprovider for brevity, but I go to the route with FirstCtrl first. I get similar issue if I go to route with SecondCtrl instead.

I don't think I've changed too much with angular-seed so am wondering if I'm doing it right with adding more controllers?

Comment: Check if your `FirstCtrl` is correct. `angular.module('myApp.controllers').controller('FirstCtrl',function($scope){});` Also note, that your loader is asynchronous. So it can sometimes load controllers before app initialization.

Comment: @akn I thought that's the reason angular-loader is in there - so scriptjs can load angular files in any order.

Comment: @Steve Yes, in any order, but with one exception: module declaration `angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])` must run before getting the module instance back `angular.module('myApp.controllers')`.

Comment: @runTarm I just don't see how I can force it to run `angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])` in the app.js file before the other modules?? Is there a way to declare the module in the seperate controller files if it doesn't exist?

Comment: You could check if module exists or not then create in every file. But it will become cumbersome as soon as the module has dependencies as you need to keep every file in sync. BTW, do you really need the async loading? Almost of the time it is not necessary because we would concat and minify all of them into a few files before pushing to Production.

Comment: @runTarm Do you have an example of checking if the module exists or not (without throwing an error)? I think async is a good idea, especially when the app starts to get bigger as I can present a meaningful display while it is loading.

Comment: @Steve Unfortunately not, you have to use `try/catch`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the $script.js `v2` (not released yet) already support the parallel script loading but also preserve the order of execution.

You can try upgrading it by copy content in the below file and replace the old one in `index-async.html`.

https://github.com/ded/script.js/blob/v2/src/script.js

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I've tried reproducing the issue again on a clean angular-seed and wasn't able to. Do you mean https://github.com/ded/script.js/blob/master/dist/script.js ? (The script you linked to is 3years old). I tried the latest script and same issue. Very strange.

Comment: No, I mean the code in `v2` branch, see [#19](https://github.com/ded/script.js/issues/19) for discussion about the order execution support. The `v2` isn't release yet. But after seeing that it is 3 years old, so I think you should start to find another library that support preserving order of execution. May be have a look at [LAB.js](http://labjs.com/), [Head.js](http://headjs.com/) or go further with [require.js](http://requirejs.org/).

Comment: Another workaround would be putting your modules declaration directly in the `index-async.html`, or if you don't mind a decrease in performance just loading `app.js` synchronously before all other scripts and put all the modules declaration in there.